# problems in using DBI

Tags: perl, dbi

I'm new to all this this stuff. I'm trying to execute the following code

```
use DBI;

my $dsn = 'DBI:mysql:db:localhost';
my $db_user_name = 'root';
my $db_password = '*******';
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $db_user_name, $db_password);

my $sth = $dbh->prepare("select id from table where field = 'value'");
$sth->execute();
($id) = $sth->fetchrow_array();
print "id is $id";
$sth->finish();
```

print outputs nothing. Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There's absolutely no error checking, so we have no way of telling whether you couldn't connect, whether you couldn't query the table (does it even exist?), whether the query succeeded, or whether zero rows were returned.  Try `my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $db_user_name, $db_password) or die "Could not connect!";`, `my $sth = $dbh->prepare("select id from table where field = 'value'") or die $dbh->errstr;` and `$sth->execute or die $dbh->errstr;`.  Also, please make sure to `use strict;` and `use warnings;`.

Comment: @Eugeny89 - The code works for me. What is the data type of `field` column?.

Comment: @JackManey, thank you for your extremely useful comment. After I added error checking, I saw that the problem is that value of the field contain '@'

Comment: Better yet, `my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $db_user_name, $db_password, {RaiseError => 1})`. Then you don't need "or die" everywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You said in one of the comments that you had an `@` in the value. If you're having a quoting issue, you should use a placeholder. Let the database driver handle the quoting issues for you:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("select id from table where field = ?");
$sth->execute($some_value);
```