# Error while inserting ? as a value in mysql using Perl

Tags: mysql, perl

I am inserting an URL in `mysql`. URL has `?`. So while inserting using Perl it's giving error as below.

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax
```

Query:

```
insert into TEST_DB values (1, 'http://website.com/hfsda/xxx-xxx-xx/?xxxx=cccd');
```

I have tried escaping `?` with `\?` also, but didn't work.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Try removing the trailing `;`.

Comment: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=7548

Comment: insert your perl code

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565978/problems-in-using-dbi/9573222#9573222

Comment: The question I asked about was not the issue. Actually the single quote was coming in between earlier text and that was showing error near by "?". So Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe what you say is true. I believe you actually asked to execute a different query. Find out what you actually executed.

---

Tested.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use DBI qw( );

my $host   = 'localhost';
my $db     = '...';
my $user   = '...';
my $passwd = '...';

my $dbh = DBI->connect(
   "dbi:mysql:host=$host;database=$db",
   $user, $passwd,
   { PrintError => 0, RaiseError => 1 },
);

$dbh->do(q{
   CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TempTable (
             id  INT,
             url VARCHAR(255)
          )
});

$dbh->do(q{
   INSERT INTO TempTable VALUES
          ( 1, 'http://website.com/hfsda/xxx-xxx-xx/?xxxx=cccd' )
});

print("ok\n");
```

Comment: The question I asked about was not the issue. Actually the single quote was coming in between earlier text and that was showing error near by "?". So Thanks for your help.